# Hugo: do not escape HTML in a page .Title when generating <title> tag in the header.html partial

Tags: hugo, hugo-shortcode

In my Hugo-based website, I often use `<span>` tags within my post titles. I am experiencing an issue where this HTML is always escaped in one particular context. As an example, take a post where the title given in the header of the Markdown file is as follows:

```
title: 'This is a title with Spanish: <span lang="es">Hola!</span>'
```

In the single.html partial of my Hugo theme, `<h2 class="posttitle">{{ .Title | markdownify }}</h2>` works correctly, it passes `This is a title with Spanish: <span lang="es">Hola!</span>` to the final HTML of the page.

However, in the header.html partial of my Hugo theme, `<title>{{ .Title | markdownify }}</title>` does **not** work. Instead, Hugo passes an escaped string to the final HTML of the page: `<title>This is title with Spanish: &lt;span lang=&#34;es&#34;&gt;Hola!&lt;/span&gt;</title>`

How can I achieve the same behavior in header.html as in single.html?

**EDIT**: My theme is exceedingly simple, the hugo-xmin theme with minimal changes. My theme’s header.html partial is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ .Site.LanguageCode }}">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{{ .Title | markdownify }} &#124; {{ .Site.Title }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="{{ "/css/style.css" | relURL }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="{{ "/css/screen.css" | relURL }}" />
    {{ partial "head_custom.html" . }}
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="sitetitle">.Site.Title</h1>
    <p id="sitedescription">{{ $.Site.Params.description }}</p>
    <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
      {{ range .Site.Menus.main }}
      <li><a href="{{ .URL | relURL }}">{{ .Name }}</a></li>
      {{ end }}
    </ul>
    <hr/>
    </nav>
```

and my theme’s single.html file is as follows:

```
{{ partial "header.html" . }}
<main>
<div class="article-meta">
<h2 class="posttitle">{{ .Title | markdownify }}</h2>
Published on <a href="{{ .RelPermalink }}"><time>{{ .Date.Format "2006-01-02" }}</time></a>
</div>
{{ .Content }}
</main>

{{ partial "footer.html" . }}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid escaping, you should use the [safeHTML](https://gohugo.io/functions/safehtml/) function.

`{{ .Title | safeHTML }}`

> This is not a working solution. Even with this function placed into the header.html partial, the HTML continues to be escaped.

This could be an issue with an older version of Hugo, I am on `v0.74.3` and it seems to be working as intended. You might want to [upgrade](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/installing/#upgrade-hugo) if you're not on the latest version or check on the [discourse](https://discourse.gohugo.io) if you are unable to upgrade.

Comment: This is not a working solution. Even with this function placed into the header.html partial, the HTML continues to be escaped.

Comment: @ChristopherC. please include your code where you are importing the partial, there is something else going on here as `safeHTML` should do exactly what you are asking - we are missing elements of your project which could be causing the issue

Comment: also note the markup of the `header` partial itself - it seems like you are attempting to put `span` tags in `head` element, which would be odd, but since there's no source there's no way to tell

Comment: I have edited my post to show the contents of the two relevant files. Note however that – as I said – replacing the `markdownify` function with `safeHTML` in header.html has no effect. A `span` tag within a `head` is not invalid HTML (the W3C’s validator shows neither an error nor a warning) and in fact it is regularly used to provide language markup for elements of the page title for the sake of screenreaders etc.

Comment: I wasn't saying it was invalid, just that it was odd because the markup then shows in some browser tab title displays - for example if you have markup in your title, Safari will show `<tag>Title</tag>` rather than `Title` and *could* also affect bookmarking

Comment: I recreated your templates and if I use `safeHTML` it works as intended, if I use `markdownify` it does *not* work, the title shows `This is a title with Spanish: <!-- raw HTML omitted -->Hola!<!-- raw HTML omitted -->` -- note I am on `v0.74.3` of hugo

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest it pushing the code to a public github repo and allow me to pull it down and test locally, there must be something else going on if `safeHTML` isn't working

Comment: I have uploaded a minimal example to [Github](https://github.com/CRCulver/nonworking-blog). I should note that I am using Hugo 0.75.1-1 as packaged by Debian (bullseye).

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded your nonworking-blog minimal example and was able to fix your issue by doing two things:

1. Put the following at the bottom of the `config.toml`:

```
[outputFormats]
  [outputFormats.html]
    isPlainText = true
```

2. Comment out line 34 in `layouts/_default/list.html` so it now looks like this:

```
{{/*
{{ template "_internal/pagination.html" . }}
*/}}
```

I did #2 because it was producing an error that I don't have time to look into now, but the key to solving your issue is `outputFormats`, which are discussed at https://gohugo.io/templates/output-formats/, especially this:

> **isPlainText** 
> use Go’s plain text templates parser for the templates. **Default:** false.

If anyone knows how to fix the line-34 problem, I'd love to understand that.

BTW, I've been using `isPlainText = true` for more than a year on my Infinite Ink site and so far have not had any problems (but I do not use any `{{ template … }}` calls).

Comment: Thank you for the attempt to help, but I cannot accept this as an answer to my query, because your proposed solution breaks pagination on my site.